# output arrays values as single object

Tags: json, object, jq

I need to be able to produce the following but without having to explicit array's indexes, so that I don't need to know input array's lenght

```
echo '[{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null},{"name":"Marc", "age":32, "car":null}]' | jq -r '{(.[0].name):.[0].age,(.[1].name):.[1].age}'
```

Produces :

```
{  "John": 30, "Marc": 32}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `add` to merge the objects.

```
jq '[ .[] | { (.name) : .age } ] | add'
```

Comment: thx a lot @choroba ! I was far from getting that "adding" objects together would merge them into one, although it is mentioned in jq's doc